# Highlight geojson object on click - Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've been trying to get a selected feature on click to highlight, but I can find the way, I'm trying from the onEachFeature style option, but doesnt work: this is what I have;

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

        style: function highL(feature){
            return{fillColor:'rgb(1,1,1)'};
        }

        layer.on({
            click: infoJ
         });
     }

function infoJ(e) {
    document.getElementById('obrr').innerHTML =       e.target.feature.properties.OBRA;
    document.getElementById('nomm').innerHTML =  e.target.feature.properties.NOMBRE;
    document.getElementById('dominn').innerHTML =  e.target.feature.properties.DOMINIO;
    document.getElementById('dirr').innerHTML =  e.target.feature.properties.DIRECC;
    document.getElementById('montt').innerHTML =  e.target.feature.properties.MONTO;
    document.getElementById('fondd').innerHTML =  e.target.feature.properties.FINANCIAM;
    document.getElementById('inicc').innerHTML =  e.target.feature.properties.FECH_INI;
}

var lay1 = L.geoJson(json_Obras,{
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {

        var markerStyle = { 
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.OBRA),
            color: "#FFF",
            fillOpacity: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            weight: 1,
            radius: 8
        };

        return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerStyle)
    },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    }).addTo(map);


function getColor(status) {
return  status == "Construccion Cancha"     ? 'rgba(182,220,86,1.0)' :
        status == "Construccion Sede Social"    ? 'rgba(233,95,194,1.0)' :
        status == "Mejoramiento Multicancha"  ? 'rgba(162,59,225,1.0)' :
        status == "Construcción"  ? 'rgba(214,112,117,1.0)' :
        status == "Remodelacion Sede Social"       ? 'rgba(211,124,192,1.0)' :
        status == "Instalacion Pasto Sintetico"  ? 'rgba(106,240,191,1.0)' :
        status == "Reconstruccion Techo"  ? 'rgba(117,195,226,1.0)' :
        status == "Construccion Balsa"       ? 'rgba(24,214,17,1.0)' :
        status == "Arreglo Sede social centro de madres"       ?    'rgba(110,231,138,1.0)' :
        status == "Mejoramiento Sede Social"       ? 'rgba(104,110,228,1.0)' :
                                   '#353942';
}
```

Its a geojson object loaded with colors by attributes, and values inside HTML divs, my ifdea is to highlight the selected feature when the info appears inside appears on the page, thanks!!

Comment: And what's the `infoJ` function? Your code snippet is missing important bits, and therefore is not reproducible.

Comment: I uploaded the complete code, thanks

Comment: And you've seen http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ ?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to highlight it on mouseover, how can I set more than 1 function to the click event??, I could only set to mouseover because the click is set to the infoj function

Comment: Open a different question for that.